# The Stanley Parable Demo won't load?

Tags: steam, the-stanley-parable

I just downloaded The Stanley Parable Demo from Steam ... Everything was running fine until I clicked Start Game, after that, a loading screen came up and it took me to a black page and wouldn't change. I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: Did you install the game on the same disk as your Operating System (which is probably C:) or did you install it on another disk ?

Comment: I was really hoping this question was, 'I started the demo and it is stuck forever on the title screen?' lol

Comment: Could possibly be a bad install.  Did you try re-installing it?

Comment: Have you had any luck re-installing?  You should also note that the Loading page takes quite a remarkable amount of time for such a small game. Usually it takes me at least a few minutes to get the whole thing loaded up, and it could be even longer with an even older computer.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old and maybe already solved, but just for others out there reading this:

I also had the problem that I could only see the menu background and nothing else.
No reaction to pressing keys or clicking.

Just exit Steam and restart it again. Then open up your game. Should be fixed now. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems funny, but I thought I was stuck because of the opening.

For others: Just start moving your character while looking at the title screen.

Answer (score -4):

I had this problem as well. In my case it was some weird corruption on my steam client -- I deleted a file and it worked. Not finding it right now but [this link may help](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=3134-TIAL-4638).

Comment: Please do not post answers which only point the reader to another website where the answer is found. Try to describe the relevant parts of the linked article with your own words instead. This makes sure that your answer will still be useful after the linked document was removed.

Comment: Please summarize the information contained at the link.  That will ensure your answer is still good even if the page linked gets removed or is otherwise unavailable.